# How to extract FreeText answer from an assignment using boto

Tags: python, boto, mechanicalturk

I'm trying to extract free-text answer submitted by workers of Amazon Mechanical Turk using the boto library.

```
assignments = conn.get_assignments(hit_id)
for assignment in assignments:
    worker = assignment.WorkerId
    answer = assignment.Answer
```

Here I expect answer to be a free-text string (the only thing that the HIT asks workers to submit) submitted by a worker, however, the code above doesn't give me that. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the assignment object in the above example will have an attribute called `answers` which is a list of `QuestionFormAnswer` objects.  Each of these objects should have an attribute called `FreeText`.

Comment: Looking at this: http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/mturk.html#boto.mturk.connection.Assignment, which suggests to follow the definitions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_AssignmentDataStructureArticle.html, I was expecting a property named `Answer` of an assignment object...

Comment: The docs do suggest that.  I looked at the code and it seemed to be accumulating the answers in an attribute called answers.  Does that exist on the object?

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the right direction. Actually, what you said above is not entirely correct for my situation, to get the input by Turkers, I had to use this: `assignment.answers[0][0].fields[0]` for each assignment. In fact, `assignment.answers[0]` gives a `ResultSet` object, and `assignment.answers[0][0]` gives a `QuestionFormAnswer` object, and I didn't find any `FreeText` attribute on that... I wonder if `FreeText` attribute only exists when you explicitly create one for the HIT using the API. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

In boto in order to get the *FreeText* information  you are looking for, you'll need to iterate over the **assignment** property **answers**. Unless you have submitted multiple forms, your form should be the first index.

This list is of type **QuestionFormAnswer**

Here is boto documentation on QuestionFormAnswer
http://sourcecodebrowser.com/python-boto/2.3.0/classboto_1_1mturk_1_1connection_1_1_question_form_answer.html

You can see that the properties you actually want are **qid** and **fields**

Here is some updated code that should make better sense.

```
assignments = conn.get_assignments(hit_id)
for assignment in assignments:
    worker_id = assignment.WorkerId
    # Iterate through question forms answers which are our fields
    for question_form_answer in assignment.answers[0]:
        field_id = question_form_answer.qid
        field_value = question_form_answer.fields
```